# Set line colors in OpenGL 3+

Tags: c++, opengl, line, opengl-3

how can I set the color for the lines I draw using openGL3 ?

the rendering function I'm using is the following

```
void renderVertex(std::vector<doubleVertex> &Poly, int32_t iniBound, int32_t endBound, int32_t Type){

    for (int32_t i = iniBound; i < endBound; i++) {
        GLfloat *ptr_polygonVertices;
        ptr_polygonVertices = createPolygonVertices(Poly[i]);

        // render OpenGL here
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, ptr_polygonVertices);
        glDrawArrays(Type, 0, Poly[i].x.size() - 1);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        delete[] ptr_polygonVertices;

    }
}
```

Inside this loop

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderVertex(Poly, 0, nBound, GL_LINE_LOOP);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

If necessary, the complete code is the listed here:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Globals.h"

GLfloat* createPolygonVertices(doubleVertex &Poly);
doubleVertex createCircle(double x, double y, double radius, int numberOfSides);
void windowInit(GLFWwindow *window);
void renderVertex(std::vector<doubleVertex> &Poly, int32_t iniBound, int32_t endBound, int32_t Type);

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow *window;
    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(0);
    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Polygon Linear Infill", NULL, NULL);
    windowInit(window);

    ////////////////////////////////////// Polygon Example //////////////////////////////////////////
    std::vector<doubleVertex> Poly{
        {   
            { 0,    23.37,  50.24,  31.26,  34.57,  1.46,   4.69,   0 },
            { 0,    11.91,  0,      -21.39, -32.22, -26.31, -13.17, 0 } 
        },
        {
            { 42.19,  35.69,  29.76,  34.46,  42.19 },
            { -4.26, 2.34, -5.2, -11.87, -4.26 }
        },
        {
            { 23.57,  26.29,  11.94, 23.57 },
            { -26.73, -17.39, -18.38, -26.73 }
        }
    };
    double x = 14.97,   y = -5.28,  r = 7.33;
    Poly.push_back(createCircle(x, y, r, 37));

    uint32_t i, nBound = Poly.size();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderVertex(Poly, 0, nBound, GL_LINE_LOOP);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}

GLfloat* createPolygonVertices(doubleVertex &Poly){
    int32_t j, n_Vertex, cnt_polygonVertices=0;

    n_Vertex = Poly.x.size();
    GLfloat *polygonVertices;

    polygonVertices = new GLfloat[(n_Vertex-1) * 2];

    for (j = 0; j < n_Vertex-1; j++) {
        polygonVertices[cnt_polygonVertices] = Poly.x[j];
        cnt_polygonVertices++;
        polygonVertices[cnt_polygonVertices] = Poly.y[j];
        cnt_polygonVertices++;
    }

    return polygonVertices;
}


doubleVertex createCircle(double x, double y, double radius, int numberOfSides){
    int numberOfVertices = numberOfSides + 2;

    double twicePi = 2.0f * M_PI;
    doubleVertex Poly;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        Poly.x.push_back(x + (radius * cos(i * twicePi / numberOfSides)));
        Poly.y.push_back(y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / numberOfSides)));
    }

    return Poly;
}

void windowInit(GLFWwindow *window){
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(0);
    }
    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT); // specifies the part of the window to which OpenGL will draw (in pixels), convert from normalised to pixels
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // projection matrix defines the properties of the camera that views the objects in the world coordinate frame. Here you typically set the zoom factor, aspect ratio and the near and far clipping planes
    glLoadIdentity(); // replace the current matrix with the identity matrix and starts us a fresh because matrix transforms such as glOrpho and glRotate cumulate, basically puts us at (0, 0, 0)
    glOrtho(0, 51, -33, 12, 0, 1); // essentially set coordinate system
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // (default matrix mode) modelview matrix defines how your objects are transformed (meaning translation, rotation and scaling) in your world
    glLoadIdentity(); // same as above comment
}

void renderVertex(std::vector<doubleVertex> &Poly, int32_t iniBound, int32_t endBound, int32_t Type){

    for (int32_t i = iniBound; i < endBound; i++) {
        GLfloat *ptr_polygonVertices;
        ptr_polygonVertices = createPolygonVertices(Poly[i]);

        // render OpenGL here
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, ptr_polygonVertices);
        glDrawArrays(Type, 0, Poly[i].x.size() - 1);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        delete[] ptr_polygonVertices;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're not using shaders, `glColor` might work. You should move to modern opengl though.

Comment: Isn't OpenGL 3 the last one? also, where should I put `glColor`? It hasn't worked for me so far..

Comment: No, we're at 4.5(?) now, but thats not a point. You don't seem to load a shader, shaders are required in a modern non-backwards compatible context, and afaik, the matrix-functions (`glMatrixMode`, `glOrtho`, `glLoadIdentity`)  are legacy functions. If `glColor` doesn't work, you have to use your own shader where you can set the color you want.

Comment: @SergioPertuz, Latest OpenGL specs is 4.5. But it doesn't mean it is widely supported. OpenGL 3.0 is from 2008, [as seen in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_3.0) , but widely supported by modern hardware, as OpenGL is nearly backward compatible. Visit [Sacha's OpenGL database](http://opengl.delphigl.de/) to verify if your target platform(s) support desired feature.

Comment: By "modern", tkausl means the _core profile_. That is, using VBOs, shaders, etc to render and not the old deprecated fixed function pipeline (which `glColor`, the matrix functions, etc are a part of).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks for the explanation, could you please send me a link with an example with these functions?